# How to make a query in same model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have a `projects` table and inside i have `type` column.

My question is how can i get all the distinct `type` first, then after that get all the projects under that type.

My goal is to output a list like this:

```
Type: Type 1
Projects: project 1, project 2, project 3

Type: Type 2
Projects: project 4, project 5, project 6
```

I could not separate the `type` and `projects` with different table and use a relationship because the database is using by another project and it has so many data already.

Answer (score 0):

in your Type model you can add a relationship with Projects and finally use the `with` method to include all the projects on each `Type` instance.

Some pseudo-code can be:

```
class Type extends Model
{
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
    }
}    


function test() 
{
    $types = Types::with('projects')->get();
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        echo $type->name;
        foreach ($type->projects as $project) {
            echo $project->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Project and Types are in the same table `projects`, i can't separate them since it already has a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
Types::select('*')
         ->get()
         ->groupBy(DB::raw('type'));
```